# custom labels bind values to comboBox in lighting component controller

Tags: lightning, customlabel

I have created Custom Label Name : **GPS_Work_Med** having two values: **ABD1** and **ABD2**
In lightning component, I have a comboBox as follows

```html
 <aura:attribute name="wbasket" type="List" default=""/>
```

Now in doInit event of the controller, I am doing like this

```js
var customLabels = $A.get("$Label.c. GPS_Work_Med");
```

I am getting the values from the custom Labels. Please let me know how to bind the custom label values to the comboBox from the doInit event of controller.

Comment: <lightning:combobox name="wb1" label="wb2"  value="{!v.wName}" aura:id="wb3" 
                                        options="{!v.wbasket}">

Comment: can this be done in the component itself ? pls let me know

Comment: I am sure you can do `cmp.set('v.wbasket', customLabels.split(', OR ANY OTHER STRING YOU HAVE USED AS SEPERATOR between ABD1 and ABD2'))`

Comment: @manjit5190, ok, I got the idea, thanks very much...